# TypeError: Cannot read property 'presetToOptions' of undefined in webpack-cli with ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am working on ReactJS application and configured `"webpack": "^2.7.0"`,
    `"webpack-cli": "^2.0.9`" but while running the webpack from cmd it has the following error.

```
const statsPresetToOptions = require("webpack").Stats.presetToOptions;
                                                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'presetToOptions' of undefined
    at processOptions (F:\reactJs_weather\React-Weather-App\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:284:57)
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 7):

`webpack-cli` needs **at least** `webpack` **version 4** to run.

If you're using older version like webpack 2 or 3, you don't need to add `webpack-cli` package seperately. It comes already built in with older versions of `webpack` itself.

From version 4, the entire CLI has been ported inside a separate package `webpack-cli`.

The fix should be to remove `webpack-cli` package or use latest version of `webpack>=4`.

There's an [ongoing PR](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/pull/297) about adding webpack 4 as peer dependency, so soon there would a warning popping up about the same.

Related discussions: [webpack is not listed as a peer](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/295), [add webpack 4 as peer dependency](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/pull/297)

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing issue and resolve using below steps:

1. Uninstall webpack-cli  `npm uninstall webpack-cli`
2. Use `"build": "webpack --config build/webpack.conf.js --color"`
   for build in package.json  instead of webpack-cli

hope it will help.

Comment: I would like to add that all I did was Step 1. I ran npm uninstall -g webpack webpack-cli, then I reinstalled them using npm i -g webpack webpack-cli and now it works.

Comment: This started happening to me suddenly after installing a package that mysteriously doesn't have any webpack dependency. Doing step 1 (`yarn remove webpack-cli`) fixed it and doesn't seem to have broken anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In `node_modules\webpack-cli\bin` change path to your real Stats.js file.

For me next path is correct:

```
statsPresetToOptions = require("../../webpack/lib/Stats.js").presetToOptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the exact same error, I had `statsPresetToOptions is not a function`, but `npm uninstall`ing and `npm install`ing `webpack-cli` solved it. Go figure.