# Webpack errors 1 after another 'cannot read property'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting this error when trying to deploy my react app with heroku, using webpack -p:

https://forum.toshitimes.com/uploads/toshitimes/original/2X/d/db3672702991720bb556a85bcf11ef1df284a073.png

I tried to uninstall webpack, I added:

```
"build": "webpack --config build/webpack.conf.js --color" but it cause another error:
```

https://forum.toshitimes.com/uploads/toshitimes/original/2X/e/ecc639d36df730e16c2bbbeb9e73370294af36a8.png

What can I do? I also tried this tutorial about setting up webpack: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/

but it didn't worked for me

Comment: Are you starting a new project with react + webpack?

Comment: Looks like `webpack-cli` might be the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035267/typeerror-cannot-read-property-presettooptions-of-undefined-in-webpack-cli-wi